# How do you list a program's all library dependencies, configs when the program has attached flags/options?

Tags: shared-library

How do you list all of a program's dependencies (libraries) and configs even if it gets argv given to it which changes the dependencies let's say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program uses the GNU C library’s dynamic linker (`ld.so`), you can run it and trace all the libraries it loads by setting `LD_DEBUG=libs`:

```
LD_DEBUG=libs yourcommand --args
```

This will allow you to determine whether changing the program’s arguments changes the libraries it loads.

Note that any libraries shown by `ldd /path/to/yourcommand` will always be loaded, that won’t vary based on program arguments. Libraries loaded using `dlopen` can vary, and this will show up using this technique.

If you want to find out what configuration files are read, use `strace`:

```
strace -e open yourcommand --args
```